# Possible to list html source in the same page as an IFrame?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

**Warning:** This may be a stupid question and the answer is probably "No".  Continue at your own peril.

Usually the target web page for an `<iframe>` is specified using the `src` attribute.  Instead of pointing the inline frame to an external source is it possible to list the html source directly within the same document?

**Background:**  I am in the process of creating content for a new website.  The site has been created for us by another organisation.  Unfortunately I can only upload content for the site through the content management system provided by this organisation.  I can create and delete pages but I'm very restricted as to creating content for them.  I only have access to the body section of the document.

One of the pages requires an image slideshow most likely using some javascript.  My job is made difficult by the fact that I don't have access to the `<head>` section.  I cannot store additional html files on the server either.  So far I haven't had a great deal of success getting my javascript to work properly.  If I could nest my slideshow in an `<iframe>` I think it would be a lot easier to implement.

Am I on the right track or is there a better way to do this?

Comment: You can add `script` tags to the `body` as well...

Comment: Are you asking if it is possible to set the HTML of the `<iframe>` dynamically using JavaScipt?

Comment: `frame.contentWindow.document.body.append`

Comment: No, instead of referencing an external html document I want to put the source directly into my iframe.

Comment: @Igor I think you are on the right track.  Although I'm too to figure it out.

Comment: On top of Igor's suggestion, you could put your content in a hidden `DIV`, or maybe even better, a `SCRIPT` tag with a non-standard `type` attribute, and reference its content by id.  Then just append that content to the frame.  It's an unusual approach, but it sounds like it would work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is possible.  You can do it this way:

```
<script>
var myiframesource="<html><body>Hello World!</body></html>";
var iw = window.frames['myiframe'].document;
iw.open();
iw.write(myiframesource);
iw.close();
</script>

<iframe name='myiframe' id='myiframe' src='about:blank' 
APPLICATION='no' scrolling='yes'></iframe>
```

Just replace "myiframe" with the name of your iframe and populate the string variable "myiframesource" with the HTML you wish to put into the iframe.

Comment: This definitely works, however when I insert it into a page on my website the text doesn't appear. Is there any reason this code might not execute correctly?

Comment: reverse the order of <script> and <iframe> tags

Comment: Tried that and doesn't seem to work.  Although the editor keeps wrapping my iframe with <p> tags.  So annoying.  I'm not sure if that is the cause of my problem though.

Comment: Never mind. For some reason the server is inserting an <img> tag right in the middle of my javascript when the page is served.  I have no idea why.